# nginx location regex and try_files

Tags: nginx, redirect

Trying to set up an inherited nginx to do my bidding, but failing a bit at doing so.

I have the typical nginx Wordpress setup:

```
location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 location ~ \.php$ {
   try_files $uri =404;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
}
```

So far, so good. But I also need to check for old URLS from a previous install that follow this pattern:

```
^(ninos|familia|hogar|mujeres|hombres)(-[a-z-]+){1,3}\.php
```

And direct those to index.php with its parameters intact, since WP will handle them with a proper 301 redirect to the new URL.

How should I do this? Should I nest another location inside the `location ~ \.php$`? Or have another separate location block outside, replicating the configuration of the `location ~ \.php$`? (Minus the "try_files $uri =404"; which I guess it'll break everything down).

Many thanks and regards. Nginx newbie. Tried the docs, but left me confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing it by adding an additional location block as this:

```
location ~ "(ninos|familia|hogar|mujeres|hombres)(-[a-z-]+){1,3}\.php$" {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
 }
```

Hopefully I'm not breaking anything else... :P

Update:

After @tero-kilkanen helpful suggestion, I replaced the above with:

```
location ~ "(ninos|familia|hogar|mujeres|hombres)(-[a-z-]+){1,3}\.php$" {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?$args last;
 }
```

Comment: You can also use `rewrite ^ /index.php?$args last;` instead of `try_files` there.